# Curious case of "Unexpected closing tag" in modern Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Suppose we have a data model, a list of objects that represent text items to be rendered in template. Each carry a text and a type. A type could be `HEADER`, `PARAGRAPH` and `LIST`. Each would correspond to a similar HTML tag, so `HEADER` would be rendered by `<h1>`, `PARAGRAPH` would be `<p>` and `LIST` would be a `<li>` eventually wrapped in an `<ul></ul>`. We have a given set of these objects. For example:

```js
[
 { textType: 'HEADER', text: 'Welcome!' },
 { textType: 'PARAGRAPH', text: 'Lorem ipsum is a lie, here are the facts:' },
 { textType: 'LIST', text: 'List item #1' },
 { textType: 'LIST', text: 'List item #2' },
 { textType: 'LIST', text: 'List item #3' },
 { textType: 'HEADER', text: 'Welcome again!' },
 { textType: 'PARAGRAPH', text: 'Lorem ipsum is not a lie after all, counterpoints:' },
 { textType: 'LIST', text: 'Another List item #1' },
 { textType: 'LIST', text: 'Another List item #2' },
 { textType: 'LIST', text: 'Another List item #3' },
 { textType: 'PARAGRAPH', text: 'That\'s all, folks!' }
]
```

The problem is quite obvious - both `HEADER` AND `PARAGRAPH` can be expressed by a one closed tag with HTML content. But `LIST` not only requires a standard `<li>` element, but also a `<ul>` (if we assume want strict HTML). How to render this within Angular template? I went about a most natural approach I could think of - `*ngFor` with some additional, unusual albeit reasonable logic added. In a way, it looks like an old-school PHP-style render.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let textItem of summaryText; let index = index">
    <h1 *ngIf="textItem.textType === 'HEADER'">{{ textItem.text }}</h1>
    <p *ngIf="textItem.textType === 'PARAGRAPH'">{{ textItem.text }}</p>
    <ng-container *ngIf="textItem.textType ==='LIST'">
        <ng-container *ngIf="(index === 0) || (summaryText[index-1] && (summaryText[index-1].textType !== 'LIST'))">
        <ul>
        </ng-container>
        <li>{{ textItem.text }}</li>
        <ng-container *ngIf="(index === (summaryText.length - 1)) || (summaryText[index+1] && (summaryText[index+1].textType !== 'LIST'))">
        </ul>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

I was somewhat surprised to learn, that this wouldn't compile. It results with `Unexpected closing tag "ng-container"`. And, sure enough, when you think about it, that makes sense. Angular enforces proper HTML so it expects the `<ul>` closure within a directive, when there's none. I understand that well enough.

But that still leaves me with an unsolved problem - how to render the list wrapped in `<ul>`, when I don't know when it will happen in that initial model? I cannot assume `<ul>` anywhere. I cannot even assume the order of the items in that model - it might as well just be a PARAGRAPH, LIST, PARAGRAPH, LIST and what not (it would result in two  lists with single item each).

Is there any way to achieve that *without* influencing the data model? I know I could theoretically change the model, make a separate list inside, detect that, start `ul` and so on. But in this case, for some reason (please assume it's reasonable and that I know what I'm talking about) I cannot change the model.

I was wondering if there's any way to make Angular render that properly. Or, if this is - perhaps - a wrong approach, there is another way to tackle this directly in the template?

Comment: This isn't really an Angular problem; before you reach the template, you need to group the items in your array such that you have all of the list items together, so you have an array of what should end up as `li`s to iterate over. It also seems like this would be a more natural fit for an [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch).

Comment: I assume you mean *"please assume reasonable and that I know what I'm talking about"*? It's rather difficult to do so when it's so obvious that a small change would make this so much easier (and if your situation is *that* idiosyncratic, this is unlikely to be useful to anybody else and therefore not a good fit for SO). *Provide the context* instead of assertions.

Comment: I've provided all the context needed. Anything else isn't necessary. My question isn't to solve the problem the other way - I KNOW how to do this. My question is asked in order to learn whether there are some Angular internals/tricks that I'm still not familiar with and that could be (even if a bit farfetched) applied in this or similar cases. If you have nothing else to add here, I'm happy for you to just say "there's none, sorry" or "I don't know" - and go about your things, instead of exercising the oldest thing in the internet of "but why would you want to do it this way...".

Comment: you anwered your own question:"Angular enforces proper HTML so it expects the <ul> closure within a directive, when there's none." I imagine the Angular team think that it's a good idea force close the tags -the idea is create a DOM and to create the DOM you need search into one directive (with open and close tag), inside the directive you look for another directive(always with opean and close tag), etc. For me is normal, e.g. the same idea is reflected in Blazor.

Comment: Indeed, that's my answer for now. I just don't know if it is definite and there's no other, hence the question. If everyone will just say "yup, that's how it is, nothing to be done about it", I'll sleep better.

Comment: Imagine you want to make a parse from an "special XML" to Json. But your XML is "some special" because can has "if" and "for". Sure I can not imagine how do it if not force that the tags gone in pairs. Well I'm not "everyone", but, personally I think that is definitive

Comment: That I realize. But that’s not the focus. I’ve obviously presented a “solution” that cannot work. I’ve just used it as an entry point. My thinking was that maybe there is other (convoluted) way to tackle this, without breaking HTML schema. For example by starting with ngFor on <ul>. Or creatively using index and SlicePipe to somehow conditionally influence the main ngFor iterator. Or maybe there is a “special” tag in Ivy to close void tags in such specific arbitrary scenarios. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

I created a bug-fixed version here for you on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p6qtvx?file=src/app/app.component.html)**.

The error is because of that the `HTML` Nested tag rules are violated here in your template:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(index === 0) || (summaryText[index-1] && (summaryText[index-1].textType !== 'LIST'))">
  <ul>
</ng-container>
```

You have a closing tag `</ng-container>` before closing inner tag `<ul>`.

In addition You have to change the JSON object data for have better structure of `<li>` items like this:

```js
  this.summaryText = [
      { textType: 'HEADER', text: 'Welcome!' },
      { textType: 'PARAGRAPH', text: 'Lorem ipsum is a lie, here are the facts:' },
      { textType: 'LIST', text: ['List item #1', 'List item #2', 'List item #3'] },
      { textType: 'HEADER', text: 'Welcome again!' },
      { textType: 'PARAGRAPH', text: 'Lorem ipsum is not a lie after all, counterpoints:' },
      { textType: 'LIST', text: ['Another List item #1', 'Another List item #2', 'Another List item #3'] },
      { textType: 'PARAGRAPH', text: 'That\'s all, folks!' }
    ]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know all that. Well, thanks for your time anyway, I guess? I suppose SO isn't a good platform to ask advanced open questions after all. But then again Angular's Github isn't either, so I didn't have much choice in this regard.

Comment: "SO isn't a good platform to ask advanced open questions". True. By definition. See the help center on the definition of on-topic questions. If it is not focused enough, then it is off-topic.